# React will not render to screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to test my React to make sure it can render but for some reason it will not work. I am using `npx create-react-app` to create my app. Please help

JavaScript:

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"

const app = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </div>
  )
}
        
ReactDOM.render(app(), document.getElementById("root"))
```

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <title>React App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How are you exactly running the app? using `npm run start`?
And what's the directory structure?
Does any error show up?
You said you're using create-react-app, but have you made changes to the app after which it stopped working? Because app scaffolded using `npx create-react-app` should be using `createRoot` not ReactDOM, unless you using older version of React.

Comment: I am using 'npm start' to start my deployment server

Comment: you mean npm **run** start? with the run keyword?

Is it working now with the solution given in the answers? Or still doesn't?

Comment: Are you saying I should use 'import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';' instead of 'import ReactDom from 'react-dom''?

Comment: No worries, good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `ReactDOM.render(app()...` should be `ReactDOM.render(<App>`, because you want to render a component not a function,

Also as you mentioned you are using `create-react-app`, the default imports are these:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
```

Which means you need to update your `ReactDOM` import

Note: every component should start with capital letter, so change `const app` to `const App`

---

Here is a snippet with the changes:

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client"

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </div>
  )
}
        
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"))
```

Answer (score 1):

already answered but comments should help to understand

```
import React from "react"
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
    
// component name should start with uppercase
    const App = () => {
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>Hello World</h1>
        </div>
      )
    }
         // render function takes a Reactelement as first parameter  
    ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"))
```